# Json.NET deserializing a selectlist / multiselectlist

Tags: asp.net, json, json.net, selectlist, selectlistitem

I serialized a [MultiSelectList](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.multiselectlist?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2) with Json.NET in ASP.NET (having TypeNameHandling enabled) and that gave the following result:

```
"MyMultiSelectList": {
    "$type": "System.Web.Mvc.MultiSelectList, System.Web.Mvc",
    "$values": [
      {
        "Disabled": false,
        "Selected": true,
        "Text": "Text1",
        "Value": "Value1"
      },
      {
        "Disabled": false,
        "Selected": false,
        "Text": "Text2",
        "Value": "Value2"
      },
      {
        "Disabled": false,
        "Selected": false,
        "Text": "Text3",
        "Value": "Value3"
      }
    ]
  }
```

When deserializing this Json back to a MultiSelectList without any custom converters using [this method](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken_ToObject__1.htm), I get a MultiSelectList with 3 SelectListItems where their Text property is set to "System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem" and their Value property is empty.

First, I assumed Json.NET fails to deserialize the SelectListItems correctly, so I made a [Custom JsonConverter](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomJsonConverterGeneric.htm) for the type SelectListItem. My converter correctly created the SelectListItems, but the outcome was still the same.

Then I tried to make a custom converter for the type MultiSelectList, but that code is never called by Json.NET.

Perhaps this problem has something to do with the fact that MultiSelectList has no default empty constructor, but I am out of options to try.

Answer (score 0):

Make a Custom class with QuickType:

```
public class CustomSelectList
    {
        [JsonProperty("MyMultiSelectList")]
        public MyMultiSelectList MyMultiSelectList { get; set; }
    }

    public class MyMultiSelectList
    {
        [JsonProperty("$type")]
        public string Type { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("$values")]
        public Value[] Values { get; set; }
    }

    public class Value
    {
        [JsonProperty("Disabled")]
        public bool Disabled { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("Selected")]
        public bool Selected { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("Text")]
        public string Text { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("Value")]
        public string ValueValue { get; set; }
    }
```

deserialize it

```
var customList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CustomSelectList>(json);
```

and then load it into a list

```
foreach (var item in customList.MyMultiSelectList.Values)
    multiSelectList.Add(new SelectListItem{ Value= item.ValueValue, Text=item.Text });
```

and populate the MultiSelectList (not yet tested)

```
var multiList = new MultiSelectList(list);
```

---

The other approach is, load it to a data structure that supports serialization first (such as, `List<KeyValuePair<string,string>>`:

```
var serializableList = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
foreach(var item in selectList)
    serializableList.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>(item.Text, item.Value));
```

And then serialize the `serializableList`, you will get

```
[{"Key":"select item value","Value":"select item text"}]
```

If you want to store more information, for example whether the item is selected, you can do `List<Tuple<string,string,bool>>`

when you need to rebuild your `MultiSelectList`, just deserialize it, add it to a `List<SelectListItem>` and then pass the list to construct the MultiSelectList (`new MultiSelectLust(list)`)

Comment: Sounds like a pretty good idea, however, I am not able to call `sonConvert.DeserializeObject<CustomSelectList>(json)` directly, since my MultiSelectList is contained in some other object at 3 levels deep.

Comment: In that case you can do `dynamic list = JObject.Parse(json);` and access it from the root level

Comment: That is also problematic I think. I don't know whether there is a MultiSelectList in there or not. Sometimes there is one, but sometimes not.

Comment: What do you want to achieve from serializing the multi select list? You can store the values in a serializable/deserializable List<T> and then do whatever you want with it

Comment: I discovered what exactly my problem was: Since I am deserializing into a Dictionairy<string, object> (and the SelectList is one of the objects), Json.NET does not trigger the custom converter for the SelectList (since the type will be object instead of SelectList). However, having a custom converter for the Dictionairy<string, object> allows me to use the class you presented for serialization and deserialization by doing the default Json.NET dictionairy serialization and interfering when I encouter a (Multi)SelectList.